# Removing Cyclic Recursion from a Context Free Grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I'm trying to solve the problem to write this CFG into an LL(1) parse table.  However, the problem is that it has cyclic left recursion between L/A and I can't find any resources that explain how to do this.

Here is the CFG in question:

```
L -> Aa | Bb
A -> La | aa
B -> bBb | ba
```

Can anyone help explain how to remove this cycle from the grammar?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you can just pull it up:

```
L -> Aa | Bb | Laa
A -> aa
B -> bBb | ba
```